# Google Collaboratory problem with numba nopython parallel jit

Tags: python, parallel-processing, google-colaboratory, numba

I have written a numba function and it is working when run by `njit` and `signatures`. But, when I try to parallel the code, it get stuck when we **just** want to define the code for Colab by running the cell (not calling the function by `fill_parallel(a, b)`). This code run on my windows python 3.8 without any problem. Why Colab have problem with this?

### The Code ([on the Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tu_YYGgpww_LbBjxBypCt8nI0P8Mu0wj?usp=sharing)):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

a = np.random.rand(10000)
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], dtype=np.int64)

@nb.njit('float64[::1], int64[::1]', parallel=True)
def fill_parallel(a, b):
    rows = a.size + 1
    cols = a.size + b.size
    res = np.empty((rows, cols))
    for i in nb.prange(rows):
        res[i, i:b.size + i] = b
        res[i, b.size + i:] = a[i:]
        res[i, :i] = a[:i]
    return res
```

### The error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28> in <module>()
----> 1 @nb.njit('float64[::1], int64[::1]', parallel=True)
      2 def fill_parallel(a, b):
      3     rows = a.size + 1
      4     cols = a.size + b.size
      5     res = np.empty((rows, cols))

                                      37 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py in propagate(self, raise_errors)
   1069                                  if isinstance(e, ForceLiteralArg)]
   1070                 if not force_lit_args:
-> 1071                     raise errors[0]
   1072                 else:
   1073                     raise reduce(operator.or_, force_lit_args)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic assert_equiv>) found for signature:
 
 >>> <unknown function>(Literal[str](Sizes of res, b do not match on <ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28> (7)), float64, int64)

There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Intrinsic in function 'assert_equiv': File: numba/parfors/array_analysis.py: Line 123.
        With argument(s): '(unicode_type, float64, int64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         AssertionError:
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/parfors/array_analysis.py:144

During: resolving callee type: Function(<intrinsic assert_equiv>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28> (7)


File "<ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28>", line 7:
def fill_parallel(a, b):
    <source elided>
    for i in nb.prange(rows):
        res[i, i:b.size + i] = b
        ^

During: lowering "id=19[LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.1153, range = (0, $rows.1162, 1))]{52: <ir.Block at <ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28> (6)>}Var(parfor_index.1153, <ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28>:6)" at <ipython-input-14-210fa9dd4b28> (6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colab embedded Numba version is 0.51.2. Updating this library using `!pip install numba --upgrade` to version of 0.55.2 solved the Colab issue with parallelization on my written code.